# Why my page count doesn't display while printing?

Tags: css, reactjs, pdf, printing

I'm using `react-to-print` to trigger printing on my reactJS app.

I have this code :

```
const print = useReactToPrint(
        {
            content: () => buildElementToPrint(), 
            pageStyle: pageStyle(),
            documentTitle: `${title}`,
            onAfterPrint: () => destroyElementToPrint()
        }
    );
```

And the `pageStyle()` method returns a string to simulate a css file.

```
const pageStyle = () => {
    return `
        @media print {
            html, body {
                height: initial !important;
                overflow: initial !important;
                print-color-adjust: exact; 
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
                background-color: var(--back-color-1) !important;
            }
            .curriculum-vitae-container {
                font-size: 11px !important;
            }
            .me, h1 {
                font-size: 15px !important;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: 12px !important;
            }
            .page-break {
                page-break-after: auto;
            }
            .experience .element {
                page-break-inside: auto;
            } 
            .element {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
            } 
        }

        @page {
            size: A4;

            @bottom-right {
                content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
            }
        }
         
    `
}

export default pageStyle;
```

Evertyhing does it well, except the fact that my page count doesn't display at all.

Can somebody help me with this ?

Thank you